# How do I move my text to the right of an image?

Tags: html, css

My code is displaying:

[image: Current Display]

I'd like it to look like this: 
[image]

Html:

```
</div>
    <div class= "Row1">
      <h2>Looking for a Job?</h2> 
      <p> Applying to a job can be such a chore.&nbsp;&nbsp;But chore no more!&nbsp;&nbsp;Send me your resume regardless of state and I will do the leg work for you. <br>
        I have helped many people apply to jobs.&nbsp;&nbsp;I am not a paid for recruiter.&nbsp;&nbsp;I will look for your dream job regardless of industry, no kickbacks just your success!</p>
            <img src= "http://laura.finance/img/road.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use your code with little modification

**HTML:**

```
<div class= "Row1">
    <div class="left">
        <h2>Looking for a Job?</h2> 
        <p> 
            Applying to a job can be such a chore.&nbsp;&nbsp;But chore no more!&nbsp;&nbsp;Send me your resume regardless of state and I will do the leg work for you. <br>
            I have helped many people apply to jobs.&nbsp;&nbsp;I am not a paid for recruiter.&nbsp;&nbsp;I will look for your dream job regardless of industry, no kickbacks just your success!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src= "http://laura.finance/img/road.png">  
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>   
</div><!-- End row -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.Row1{
  padding: 15px;
  background-color:red;

}
.right img{
    width: 100%;
}
.left{
  Float:left;
  Font-size: 30px;
  width: 70%;
}
.right{
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}
.clearfix{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Awesome- can you explain to me exactly what the clearfix does here?

Comment: @Rahul Menon: Actually both the children of .row1 element are floated i.e. float left and float right so, the .row1 element will not get height Therefore, you will have to clear the floats at the end, in this way the row1 element will get height (div.clearfix is an empty div with no floats)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Flexbox**

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1;
}

.right img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left">
    <h2>This is title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione saepe, dolorum alias facere numquam sit explicabo rem hic mollitia. Quas suscipit odio est, temporibus error labore! Porro asperiores officiis dicta.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired layout in **2 quick steps**:

1. Move the `<img>` to the beginning of `div.Row1`
2. Apply `float: right;` and `padding-left: 20px;` to the `<img>`

See:

```css
.Row1 > img {
float: right;
padding-left: 20px;
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row1">
<img src="http://laura.finance/img/road.png" alt="A remote track through fields" />
<h2>Looking for a Job?</h2> 
<p> Applying to a job can be such a chore. But chore no more! Send me your resume regardless of state and I will do the leg work for you.</p>
<p>I have helped many people apply to jobs. I am not a paid for recruiter. I will look for your dream job regardless of industry, no kickbacks just your success!</p>
</div>
```